# How to use substring (or cut strings) in React

Tags: reactjs

While practicing React I wanted to take it further by showing complete post only if the post id == 2.
I wanted to do with `substring` but didn't work, then I added `toString()` but still not working.

```
  <p> {postId == 2 ? post.body : post.body.toString().substring(2, 3)  } </p>
```

Here is a complete example, just uncomment the commented line
https://codesandbox.io/s/useeffect-practice-fetch-gskpf?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Can you provide a sample JSON structure you are using.

Comment: * Are you sure post.body isn't empty (null, undefined, "", ...). Try console.log(post.body).
* Are you sure postId is different from 2?

Comment: Here is a complete example, just uncomment the line to see the problem
https://codesandbox.io/s/useeffect-practice-fetch-gskpf?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before getting data from `fetchPost` and call `setPost` your `post` is empty object ==> `post.body` is undefined. Add question mark to check if it existing do the work

```
// add question mark after post and body
<p> {postId == 2 ? post.body : post?.body?.toString().substring(2, 3)  } </p>
```

Normal version

```
<p> {postId == 2 ? post.body : post.body ? post?.body?.toString().substring(2, 3) : 'loading...'  } </p>
```

[Check the codesandbox for demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/useeffect-practice-fetch-l8md0)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.... Hope it helps!!!!

```js
let someword = "Hello there!";
console.log(someword.substring(0, 4));
```